# application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: NOT Called iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to save some push notification data in application.But I can not save data if the user terminate the app by swiping up the app on the multitask viewer (Suspend or not runing state).I used application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: to handle it.But still I could not save push notification data

I have set App settings like this

[image]

[image]

And Payload,

```
 {
    "aps" : {
       "alert" = "Notification with custom payload",
    },
   "content-available" = 1
 }
```

And application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: looks like this

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {

        NSLog(@"Inactive");

        //Show the view with the content of the push

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

    } else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {

        NSLog(@"Background");

        NSString *info = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"]valueForKey:@"alert"];

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Active");

        //Show an in-app banner

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

    }
}
```

Comment: @Ewan Mellor ,@Anbu.Karthik .Ok .Tell me ,Are there any way to save push notification data when app is suspended state?

Answer (score 0):

This is completely normal.  If you check the console log for the device, you will see a message from the system stating that it will not wake-up the app because it was terminated by the user.

Comment: The problem is not called application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler when app is in suspend or not running state.Application does not want to open when notification received

Comment: Apple documentation is clear.  You are seeing the designed and intended behavior.  If you want to know what else you can do, you have to ask another question.  Warning: that question, too, has already been asked and answered.

Comment: Instead of being a know it all you could've posted the link to that question @Avi

Comment: It's not my job to track down such information.  If the OP wants it, he knows how to find it.  If nothing else, posting the question will get an answer or a link to the question he duplicated.  I answered the question posted here, and that's enough.